# pass information about event prevention through angular's event object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is how I now use arguments to pass information about whether the event should be prevented:

```
var data = {
    cancel: false
};
$scope.$emit("nodeadd.nodeselector", data);
if (!data.cancel) {
    $scope.addNodeCb(type, subtype);
}

...
// preventing event
$scope.$on("nodeadd.nodeselector", function(event, data) {
    data.cancel = true;
});
```

Is there any way I could accomplish the same using event object returned by $emit?

Comment: please give us more information about what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: What exactly is not clear? I'm trying to come up with a mechanism to prevent event from event listener

Comment: for example, why do you have to use an event? do you need to pass it through different controllers?

Comment: I'm using an event because that is how the system is designed. It's not what question is about :)

Comment: I am asking because your listener does not make any sense to me. Therefore, I am trying to help by finding maybe another solution which is suitable for you.

Comment: I understand, thanks. But this is simplified example so this listener doesn't do anything but preventing the event

Comment: Well, then `event.preventDefault();`?

Comment: Yeah, it seems that angular event has this method implemented, probably it borrowed it from jquery event. Thanks!

Comment: Glad we worked it out ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the [Angular FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq), you can use a subset of jQuery like `preventDefault();`

> Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.